# Can't host Go backend on Heroku

Tags: go, heroku

I have a go application that I want to host on Heroku. This is in my procfile :

```
web: studentData
```

I am trying to host this project: https://github.com/ArjunMalhotra07/studentData

These are the logs :

```
2022-10-21T08:47:14.341704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-21T08:47:15.169264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `studentData`
2022-10-21T08:47:16.764117+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022/10/21 08:47:16 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
2022-10-21T08:47:16.955065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-21T08:47:17.025025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-21T11:44:18.962122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-21T11:44:19.657482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `studentData`
2022-10-21T11:44:21.125150+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022/10/21 11:44:21 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
2022-10-21T11:44:21.306577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-21T11:44:21.749452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-21T12:25:14.309144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-21T12:25:15.245316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `studentData`
2022-10-21T12:25:16.869878+00:00 app[web.1]: 2022/10/21 12:25:16 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
2022-10-21T12:25:17.061078+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-21T12:25:17.121535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-21T13:47:36.216585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=student-data-go.herokuapp.com request_id=dff4bc20-5ba3-40e9-b70e-be468298c454 fwd="103.217.117.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T13:47:36.923361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=student-data-go.herokuapp.com request_id=f33ae591-8ee3-434b-999c-7a66c273fb77 fwd="103.217.117.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I can't make out whats wrong.

Please let me know if anything else needs to be specified to get to the root of the issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go, but with how you've configured your database connection. Which MySQL addon are you trying to use on Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

Check you connection to MySql. The error clearly says that there is a problem connecting to the db. Inside your github repo I've found this:

db, err = sql.Open("mysql","aman:Mysql_Witcher7%@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/studentInfo")

You should change 127.0.0.1 which is localhost to some env variable that points to your production db host.